# about CppWinRT internal 2

Tags: c++-winrt

We know that the implementation class does not inherit from `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknow`, for example

```
struct App : ApplicationT<App>
{...}
```

`App` does not have the `as` and `try_as` member functions, so how does the following code work?

```
// base.h (v2.0.190620.2 line 509)
template <typename D, typename I>
struct require_one : consume_t<D, I>
{
    operator I() const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<D const*>(this)->template try_as<I>(); // A
    }
};
```

for the code at A, `D` is in fact `App`, it should not work. Please help, many thanks!!!

Comment: `ApplicationT` is composable, so the `try_as` is coming from `root_implements_composing_outer<true>`.

Comment: Thanks. So if we want to use ```implements``` and ```require``` or ```base``` together , we must include ```composing``` marker in the ```implements```'s interface list. These make implementation class the outer role in the composition relation.

Comment: No, that's misusing the "composing" marker. Don't use it unless you have a composable class. Please explain why you want to use "implements" and "require" together. They are for different purposes.

Comment: By together, I mean something like ```ApplicationT```

Comment: ApplicationT isn't using "composing" in order be able to use both implements and requires. It is using implements and requires in order to support "composing". Why do you think you need both? Are you trying to make a composable class? Then just declare it in midl and let the midl and cppwinrt compilers do the work.

Comment: "Why do you think you need both?" : I conclude this just from the fact that ```composing``` marker introduce the ```try_as``` and without this marker, the conversion operator introduced by ```require``` will fail. "Are you trying to make a composable class?" : No, I am far from that at this moment. Just exploring the CppWinRT without specific purpose :).

Comment: `require` is in the `winrt::impl` namespace and is not intended for use by apps. It is part of the internal infrastructure of C++/WinRT.